# Axios network error in Nodejs and React Native Expo

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, expo, mern

I am using Nodejs, Express, MongoDB, and React Native expo. I created a simple register form. I tested my REST API for registering users using Postman. Still, when I try registering the user using the React native app running on an `Expo Android` device, it shows a Network error.

> Axios error: Network error

This is the `handleRegister` from the react-native register form:

```
const userdata = {
        username,
        email,
        password,
      };
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://10.0.2.2:5000/register",
        userdata
      );

      console.log("Registration data :", response.data);

      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log(data.message);
        navigation.navigate("Home");
      } else {
        console.error(data.error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Register error: ", error);
    }
```

Comment: did you try pinging the address of your server on a different device aside from using postman on the same device? I suspect that the server is not accessible outside the system it is running on. If not maybe your phone is not connected to the wifi.

Answer (score 0):

This error is mainly caused by your garget and your pc/mac or on different networks.
Please try checking whether both the phone and pc/mac are on the same network.
Or Create a hotspot from your machine and connect to it on your phone.
The network will be okay.